# Google Map view based on zoom and number of markers

Tags: google-maps

does anybody know what this type of map is? Sort of heatmap showing numbers of markers until zooming in.
http://soundaroundyou.com/
http://www.aarhus.dk/sitecore/content/Subsites/AarhusBycykel/Home/Information/Bycykelkort.aspx?sc_lang=da

Best J

Comment: is your question how this type of maps is called or how to create them?
Just asking for the name of this style does not belong to SO imho and if you ask how to create them, you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marker Clustering : this is an addon for google map :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: Thank you we will try this out!

Answer (score 0):

Its a heat map cluster. This shows grouping based on cluster. When you zoom out the cluster points gets increased. On clicking on the count, map gets drill down and expand and shows all the clustered region.

Its one of the feature of google maps